# Recurrence relation and initial conditions for the number of ways to build a stack of height n cm using blocks.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm working on a problem, and I just want to make sure that my work is correct. The problem goes like this:

> Suppose that we have a collection of building blocks consisting of red, blue, and
>   green blocks of height 1 cm and yellow blocks of height 3 cm. Write a recurrence
>   relation and initial conditions for the number of ways to build a stack of height n cm using these blocks.

I let S<sub>n</sub> be the total number of ways, and this is my solution:

S<sub>n</sub> = S<sub>n-1</sub> + S<sub>n-1</sub> + S<sub>n-1</sub> + S<sub>n-3</sub>

S<sub>n</sub> = 3S<sub>n-1</sub> + S<sub>n-3</sub>

And with our initial conditions:

S<sub>0</sub> = 1

S<sub>1</sub> = 3 (blue or red or green)

S<sub>2</sub> = 9

S<sub>n</sub> = 3(9) + 1 = 28.

Comment: Your recurrence is fine, but the right hand side on the right does not depend on $n$ so it cannot be correct.  It is correct for $S_3$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, do you mean that Sn = 3(9) + 1 = 28 is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, $S_4$ is greater than $28$.  By your recurrence it is $3 \cdot 28 + 3=87$.  $S_n$ has to depend on $n$.  In fact it will be the sum of three terms like $ar^n$ where the $r$s are the three roots of $x^3=3x^2+1$ and the $a$s are chosen to fit the small numbers.  The largest root is about $3.1008$ so the number of solutions will grow like $3.1008^n$ as $n$ gets large.

Comment: Ah -- I think that may have been an error in my notes, and I meant to write S3 instead of Sn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your answer is correct. I've done this one before! Similar answer here: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160419091913AAPO82O